# How to let an User draw and save polygons on an HTML Site?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, polygon

I want to let an User draw Polygons on an HTML Site. I also want to enable the user to save and load his drawn polygons in an human-readable file like svg or xml.

It is important that i can read out some properties of the polygons, like its position on the page. I don't want to have an online drawing program like jquery-svg.

I have looked at http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/demo/linepolygon.htm , but this tool is not ver sophisticated yet...

Do you have any ideas / tools that could help me ?

Best,

Hans

Comment: You could fork SVG Edit to do what you want https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/ Here is an implementation of SVG I made http://editor.method.ac.

Comment: Hi, sounds not bad. Is there a way to give kind of an id to a rectangle/circle or polygon? And is it possible to integrate a png-file as a background?

Comment: In SVG Edit orignal http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html you can change the id. Background patterns are not implemented yet. It's not a trivial task but it is doable.